# Population standard deviation

Tags: matlab, statistics

I want to do something very simple in MATLAB. I want to calculate the population standard deviation (i.e. I want the denominator n instead of n-1 as reviewed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15098/sample-standard-deviation-vs-population-standard-deviation)).

The MATLAB default is to calculate the sample standard deviation.  As in this example:

```
example = [0.555158185377949    0.572544871140911   0.566844451709150   0.585793022458150   0.577877363402946   0.564285735627449   0.582162844985863   0.576409646607226   0.583718583332482   0.577417064869028]
std(example)
ans =
     0.0096
```

For MuPad, it appears that [adding 'Population'](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/stats-stdev.html) should give me the population standard deviation.  In MATLAB, adding `'Population'` does give a result different from plain `std()`:

```
test1=std(example,'Population')
test1 =
       0.0087
```

But that result does not seem to be the same as the square root of the population variance:

```
sqrt(var(example,1))
ans =
    0.0091
```

Note that the 'sample' standard deviation does equal the square root of the 'sample' variance, as you would expect:

```
sqrt(var(example))
ans =
     0.0096
std(example)
ans =
     0.0096
```

So the problem is just for population standard deviation. Am I missing something? Is there a MATLAB command to give the population standard deviation (instead of the sample standard deviation)?  Or do I always need to take the square root of the population variance to calculate population standard deviation?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [`std`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/std.html)? By default, `std` normalizes by N-1 (`var` too), not N as you seem to be stating. Switching between the two is just a matter of reading the documentation. Matlab and MuPAD are two separate environments – the functions and documentation are distinct so look at whichever is relevant to you.

Comment: Thanks @horchler.  I did read the documentation for std for my version of Matlab (R2014b).  It does not say now to normalize by N (which is what I want) instead of N-1.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "It does not say now to normalize by N". Here's the archived documentation [specific to R2014b](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2014b/matlab/ref/std.html) – normalization is discussed right in the description. Using `help std` will show you something similar.

Comment: Thanks @horchler.  Sure enough, it is there.  I somehow missed it the first five times I read that documentation!  I'll add the solution below in case it is useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'flag' determines whether you use the sample standard deviation (normalized by n) or population standard deviation (normalized by n-1).

```
std(example,1)

ans =

    0.0091
```

Which is the same as sqrt(var(example,1)).